# How does this formula for Jacobians hold?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $x = \phi(u,v,w)$, $y = \psi(u,v,w)$, and $u = f(r,s)$, $v = g(r,s)$, $w= h(r,s)$. Then how does the following formula for the Jacobians hold? 
$$ { \partial(x,y) \over \partial(r,s) } = { \partial(x,y) \over \partial(u, v) } { \partial(u,v) \over \partial(r,s) } + { \partial(x,y) \over \partial(v,w) } { \partial(v,w) \over \partial(r,s) } + { \partial(x,y) \over \partial(w,u) } { \partial(w,u) \over \partial(r,s) }.$$